# Setting the id on element created by #each helper

Tags: ember.js

How can I set the id for elements created by the Ember.js handelbars helper #each?

If you take a look at http://jsfiddle.net/7QL5z/ I tried to define an id on calling the #each helper.

The resulting HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="ember191" class="ember-view">
  <ul>
    <li id="ember349" class="ember-view"> Animal - Animals </li>
    <li id="ember389" class="ember-view"> Android - Androids </li>
    <li id="ember427" class="ember-view"> Human - Humans </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Neither the div nor the ul (that would be the most usable way) get the specified id.
Is it possible at all? If not: how can I access these elements via Ember?

Answer (score 3):

I tried setting 'elementId' instead of 'id' on the '#each' but it didn't seem to work either...

Otherwise you can create an animals list view

```
App.AnimalsListView = Ember.CollectionView.extend({
  tagName: 'ul',
  contentBinding: 'App.itemsController.content',
  classNames: ['animals'],
  elementId: 'animalsList',
  itemViewClass: Ember.View.extend({
    classNames: ['animal'],
    templateName: 'ember/templates/animals/animal',
    elementId:Ember.computed(function(){
      'animal-'+this.getPath('content.name')
    })
  })
});
```

In your animal template:

```
{{ content.get('name') }} - {{ content.get('pluralized') }}
```

And finally in your main html file

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars">
  {{ view App.AnimalsListView }}
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can just specify the id on a view using `id="whatever"`, but it won't work on a `{{#each}}`

http://jsfiddle.net/tomwhatmore/TJvR6/

Might be a slightly more elegant solution but what I've put in that js fiddle seems to work.